# Pivot Table in Adwords Script Alernative

Tags: google-apps-script, pivot-table, google-ads-api

Manipulating Pivot table in Google Adwords Script is not yet supported. Is there any script or project alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a new tab, and insert in any cell formula with a Google Query like that:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1fSdx7f3rg_Vp_11yFuqKZmHraqFit8A", "Headline1!A1:J"), "select Col1, sum(Col4), sum(Col5), sum(Col7), sum(Col8) group by Col1", 1)
```

, where you specify the source of the data, the query and a headers parameter.

Note, that the columns should be named like this: Col1,.Col2 etc. So the columns order should be strict (if you want to generate a report regularly).

Google Visualization API Query Language (used in the "query" parameter) is almost the same as SQL, but with some limitations on commands that can be used.